# Counter for a list adding up to 10

Tags: python-2.7, list, loops

I'm currently stuck on a question regarding lists and formulating codes. I have to 
For example, if list = [4,6] I would have to return 2. (4+6) and (6+4). This code has to work for any length of list and no two numbers will be the same within the list. I'm new to lists and and stuck on how to begin coding.

```
def countsum(list):
```

Would appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def count_list_aux(num_possibilities, a_list, i, j):
    if i == j: # Only 1 item to check now.
            if a_list[i] == 10: # The item itself is 10 so that can be a combo.
                    return num_possibilities + 1
            else: # Otherwise we are done.
                    return num_possibilities

    else:
            combo = a_list[i] + a_list[j]
            if combo == 10: # (4,6) for instance.
                    return count_list_aux(num_possibilities+2, a_list, i+1, j-1)
            elif combo > 10: # (4,8) for instance. Clearly 8 needs to go when we have a sorted list.
                    return count_list_aux(num_possibilities, a_list, i, j-1)
            else: # (4,7) for instance. Clearly 4 needs to go when we have a sorted list.
                    return count_list_aux(num_possibilities, a_list, i+1, j)

def countsum(a_list):
        a_list = sorted(a_list)
        return count_list_aux(0, a_list, 0, len(a_list)-1)

print(countsum([4,6,3,7,5,2,8]))
```

I have made a recursive solution where I simply sort the list  (ascending order) and then recursively add up left most (`i`) and right most (`j`) and check if they add up to 10. If they do, then I increment `num_possibiltiies` by 2 (eg. 6,4 and 4,6 are 2 combos). If the sum is greater than 10, then I decrement `j` by 1 because clearly, the current index `j` cannot work with any other values in the list (list is sorted). Similarly, if the sum is smaller than 10, I increment `i` by 1 as the current index `i` cannot work with any other values to get a sum of 10 (it failed with the largest value at index `j`).

Comment: Would this work for lists that have higher than a length of 2?

Comment: If you're not sure, you can test my code out. The above code does test for `[4,6,3,7,5,2,8]` and it outputs 6 as we have (4,6), (6,4), (3,7), (7,3), (2,8), (8,2). If you find this answer useful, it would be greatly appreciated if you press the "tick" next to my answer. That way future users will know this is a working solution to your problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks! 1 more question, what if we're not allowed to have (i,j) in the def line like you ahve there? I am not allowed to change def countsum(list): part.

Comment: Just edited my answer - i am still using your `countsum(list)` function BUT inside that function i call an "auxillary" recursive function (`count_list_aux(0, a_list, 0, len(a_list)-1)`) which uses `i` and `j` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The function can also be implemented using:

```
from itertools import combinations
from math import factorial

def countsum(L):
    x = 10
    n = 2
    return sum(factorial(n) for c in combinations(L, n) if sum(c) == x)
```

The factorial is because combinations produces tuples that are sets of items, rather than counting each of the permutations, simply compute their count. As the factorial depends on a constant it can be hoisted:

```
def countsum(L):
    x = 10
    n = 2
    return factorial(n) * sum(1 for c in combinations(L, n) if sum(c) == x)
```